# Continuous function in [0,1] for each x f(x)>x

Tags: calculus, continuity

Continuous function in [0,1] for each x f(x)>x, 
Prove that exists c>0 for each x in [0,1] f(x)>x+c.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you know about continuity? Do you know any special property that $[0,1]$ has which may be relevant?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are some helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, please refer to this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$g(x)=f(x)-x$ is continious and positive in  [0,1], so has minimum $g(c_0)=a>0$. Take $c=\frac{a}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

Assume the contrary; then there exists a sequence $(x_n)_n$ in $[0,1]$ such that $|f(x_n)-x_n|\rightarrow0$. By Bolzano-Weierstrass, $(x_n)_n$ has a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_k})_k$ with limit $x\in[0,1]$. By continuity, $f(x_{n_k})\rightarrow f(x)$. But then $|f(x_{n_k})-x_{n_k}|\rightarrow|f(x)-x|$, so we have $f(x)=x$; contradiction.